# How do I add custom ranges and points in the axes of a Base R plot?

Tags: r, plot

Let's consider a vector and plot it.

```
s1 <- sample(100:1000,32,replace = T)
plot(s1)
```

The plot I get has a Y-Axis that ranges from 0-1000 with points in the intervals of 200 (0,200,400,600,800,1000) and this is happening implicitly.

If I use `ylim` argument, apparently or to be honest, evidently, I can now have a custom range,

```
plot(s1,ylim = c(0,1500))
```

The points on Y Axis now are 0-1500 as indicated but with the points in the intervals of 500 (0,500,1000,1500), this is happening without my control.

My question, how can I have custom points with custom intervals on the X or Y axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `axis()` to set your limits : on either x, y, or both

```
s1 <- sample(100:1000,32,replace = T)
plot(s1, yaxt = "n")                  # `yaxt` prevents y-axis labels to be printed
axis(2, yaxp=c(10, 1000, 10), las=2)  # 'las' helps to align the tick mark labels along the axis or perpendicular
# 'yaxp' helps to set the break points you desire. Learn more from ?par
```